Furnace not Shutting Down Properly
I have a York Diamond 80 furnace with a newer main board.  The furnace worked great all winter and just started having issues this morning.  Here is what happens.

I power the unit off for 20 seconds to reset the board.
I turn back on and the thermostat triggers the start of the sequence.
The furnace works as expected and runs for the usual amount of time.
It begins its shutdown sequence and turns the main blower off.
The flames never shut off and continue to go until it triggers an overheat shut down I believe.
The trouble shooting light now starts blinking red, 4 blinks and a pause. “Open High Limit Switch” is the error code.
At next power on cycle the exhaust fan kicks on, but the flame igniter never glows and the gas never turns on.

I find it odd that the flames continue after the blower shuts off.
Any thoughts?

Is there still 24V on the gas valve terminals after the main blower has shut off?

I will check now

I have three terminals on the gas valve (PM, C, HI). I measured between PM and C.  Unfortunately this time the furnace worked as expected and the gas did not remain on.  I will try again and see if I can get it to hang up.  The voltage was 24v when the gas was on.

Well it worked perfectly again.  We will see if we make it through the night.  If not I will mess with it some tomorrow.  Thanks for the help!

So I was able to check it this morning.  After the cycle ends and the blower kicks off, there is still 24v between PM and C.  This remains until the unit triggers the 4 blink error and shuts off the gas.  I wonder if a low speed blower is supposed to be running during that time.
